# kubernetes and/or terraform configuration issue causing performance degradation?

Tags: performance, kubernetes, terraform

I'm migrating an e2e test stack from `docker compose` based setup to `kubernetes`. As part of this migration, I'm also creating `terraform` modules for individual services that make up a product.

A single e2e stack - ATM - is composed of ~50 pods and starts up in out 5 minutes (I run dedicated DBs, in-memory data stores, esb integration tools, external mocked services, etc.., per stack, hence the high number of pods).

During testing I would like to start up as many of those complete stacks as possible.

Currently I have a k8s cluster with 9 nodes:

- six 64GB RAM, 512GB SSD, with latest gen i5 CPUs (max-pods with default 110) and
- three 256GB RAM, 1TB SSD, with 18 core Xeon CPU (max-pods set to 330 on each) nodes.

I'm using my `terraform` modules to start up the stacks (the modules mostly define kubernetes resources).

My expectation would be that I can fire up ~30 stacks in parallel without major hiccups. I also would expect that startup times follow - to a reasonable extent - a function like `st` = ((`#s` + `#n`) % `#n`) * `ss-st`, where:

- `st` denotes the overall *startup time*,
- `#s` denotes *number of stacks*,
- `#n` denotes *number of nodes* and finally
- `ss-st` denotes *single stack startup time*.

However, reality is very different. Blue columns shows actual startup times (measured in seconds), while red shows, what my idealized expectation is.

Installed Prometheus operator and I have some metrics, but non explain to me (yet) where is the bottleneck in this case (disk utilization seems to get maxed out on master nodes from time to time, but they alone does not seems to explain the end figures).

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a question: how is this related to terraform?

Comment: @MarkoE updated my description. I'm using my own terraform modules to create kubernetes resources (pods, services, etc...)

Comment: But the issue is not related to terraform right? This is more related to performance?

Comment: But anyway, terraform is trying to create resources in parallel, not sure if it can do 30 at a time. There is the option to define how many of those you want to run in parallel: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/apply#parallelism-n

Comment: I've already pumped up terraform parallelization factor (I'm using a multiplier related to stack counts). I'm not sure where the bottleneck is is, that is why I mentioned terraform as I noticed that start up time was different on my old mac and my newer dell laptop (where terraform was running from).

Comment: Ah, I'm guessing Win based? It's not really the best OS to use terraform on. 

Comment: I’m using ubuntu